# aiohttp https request with an http proxy fail

Tags: python, proxy, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am building a test project to learn asyncio. I am building a progam that fetches multiple pages over a proxy server.

It works fine for http pages, but it fails with https pages. When i use the regular request library i get https pages to work aswell, but not with asyncio.

I isolated the code that breaks:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, proxy="http://192.168.0.2:9001") as response:
            print(await response.text())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(fetch("https://google.com")) #http websites do work
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 936, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1050, in create_connection
    transport, protocol = await self._create_connection_transport(
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1080, in _create_connection_transport
    await waiter
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 395, in _loop_writing
    self._write_fut = self._loop._proactor.send(self._sock, data)
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 525, in send
    self._register_with_iocp(conn)
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 714, in _register_with_iocp
    _overlapped.CreateIoCompletionPort(obj.fileno(), self._iocp, 0, 0)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/data/Python/playground/sayncio_session.py", line 10, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(fetch("https://google.com")) #http websites do work
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:/data/Python/playground/sayncio_session.py", line 6, in fetch
    async with session.get(url, proxy="http://192.168.0.2:9001") as response:
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1012, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 480, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 523, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 855, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_proxy_connection(
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 1093, in _create_proxy_connection
    transport, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "C:\Users\GG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\connector.py", line 943, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host google.com:443 ssl:default [The parameter is incorrect]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am using aiohttp=3.6.2 and python=3.8.2

How can i fix this error?

Comment: Try switching to the selector event loop instead of the proactor. E.g. add `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())` somewhere at the top of the module, does this resolve the error?

Comment: @hoefling, This did work!! Thanks alot. Do you also knwo why i have to add this line?
Do you also know why i have to add this line? Its weird that selecting an event loop policy make https over http proxies work.

Comment: Sure, see the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have also experienced this issue with `aiohttp` on Windows when trying to use the [`ProactorEventLoop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.ProactorEventLoop). Since Python 3.8, it is now the default event loop on Windows (instead of the [`SelectorEventLoop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.SelectorEventLoop)), so until the the library gets a fix, the workaround is to switch back to `SelectorEventLoop` explicitly:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(url):
    ...

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(fetch(...))
```

Related: [issue #2245](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/2245) in `aiohttp`'s tracker.